# What is EMX files

Tags: java, xml, uml, cyber-ark

What is EMX files and why do we use it. I'm doing some analysis and here I got these files. I explored and get to know that it is something related to UML but I'm not clear on this.

Comment: google says : Music file used by eMusic Download Manager. How did you get that file ? is it a text file you can visualize/edit ?

Comment: This file is linked to one of my java application. I guess somehow its related to IBM RSA

Comment: That file contains class names and is coded in UML/XMI

Comment: `This file is linked to one of my java application` : *one of* does help us to help you, which one ? `That file contains class names and is coded in UML/XMI` edit your question to put that kind of information and all other details you know

Answer (score 3):

File extensions are free. So the name of an extension is not sufficient to give assurance about its content, unless it’s a format used by a popular software package. Name conflicts are not uncommon.

If narrowing down the search with some contextual information such as XML and UML that you provide in the tags, it seems to be a file format used by [Rational Software Architect](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_Software_Architect) to save UML models, according to [this](https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/15.1/model_publishing/import_emxuml2_files.html) and [this](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/documents/vpuserguide/124/127/6526_importingrat.html) website of other popular UML tools.

You now have to confirm this hypotheses by analyzing the file content.